# Are $(1, 0)$ tensors always vectors? (resolved)

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

An $(r, s)$ tensor $T$ is defined to be an element of the tensor product of a vector space and its dual:
$$T \in T^r_sV := V^{\otimes r}\otimes V^{* \otimes s}.$$ However, when $V$ is finite dimensional, we have an isomorphism $$V \cong T^1_0V$$in which case every vector is considered a tensor, i.e., and element of a tensor space. However, according to Simon Rea's notes from Frederic Schuller's Geometric Anatomy of Theoretical Physics, this is not true in infinite dimensions. Does this mean that the physicists conception of a vector as a $(1, 0)$ tensor is not always true?

Comment: a vector space is isomorphic to its (algebraic) dual if and only if it is finite dimensional.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner   $T^1_0V$ is not the algebraic dual of $V$.

Comment: Isn't $T^1_0V = V^{\otimes 1} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes 0}$ **equals** (not isomorphic) to $V$?

Comment: That's what one would think, but the notes say otherwise.

Comment: @azif00 I'm so sorry. I just read the notes and I was completely wrong. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: Maybe the notes are alluding to this: For infinite dimensional Banach spaces many books define $T^r_s(V)$ as the set of multilinear maps $L(V^*,\dots,V^*,V,\dots,V;\mathbb R)$, $r$ copies of $V^*$, $s$ copies of $V$. See Lang, Klingenberg, or Marsden & Ratiu. In finite dimensions this agrees with the algebraic tensor product. For infinite dimensional tensor products on TVS, see Grothendieck's thesis, or F. Treves.

Comment: @p.co no, I don't think that they are. I made a mistake in reading the notes. What it was really saying was that $T^0_1 = V^* \cong V$ in finite dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lecture notes actually state that $$T^0_1V \cong V$$ only in finite dimensions. However, $T^1_0V := V$, and so every vector is a rank $(1, 0)$ tensor, since the vector space $V$ is equal to $T^1_0V$. So, no the physicists are not wrong, every vector is indeed a tensor.